# Past perfect in context

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

Put the verb into the correct form, past perfect **(had broken)** or past simple **(broke)**:

> Sorry I'm late. The car ....... down on my way here.

According to the book, the correct answer is 'broke' (past simple).

I agree, but perhaps I repaired my car on my way to a place and that might be the reason why I am late. Could past perfect be used in this context?

Comment: In general, avoid using the perfect tenses unless there's a good reason.  In this sentence there's no relationship between two events, so *broke* makes the most sense.  You'd only use *had broken* if you wanted to suggest it happened before some other significant event ... but even then it's hard to think of a good example.  *Broke* works in almost every situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect is a 'relative tense', and to use a past perfect you must establish a past context—a 'Reference Time'— to which it is related.

> <sup>no</sup>I'm late because my car had broken down.  —*This doesn't work because the context is present: "I **am** late".*
>
> <sup>ok</sup>I'm late because I had to stop on the way: my car had broken down. —*This works because past-tense **had to** establishes a past context.*

Comment: Can't past perfect be relative to an implicit past context?

Comment: Yes; but your discourse establishes a **present** RT, which must be explicitly shifted to license a past perfect.